# Prevent dispatch if form is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, redux, react-redux

Currently, I'm working on a project where I used react redux. I'm sending a form's data, and a button causes the loading to begin. The issue is that anytime I click a button while the form is empty, the button's state-driven loading continues. How can I stop the button from executing while the input field is empty?

```
  const formSubmit = () => {
    const payload = {
      email: emailRef.current?.value,
      password: passwordRef.current?.value,
    };
    if (payload.email || payload.password !== '') {
      dispatch(authLogin(payload, nav));
    } else {
      console.log('error');
    }
  };


 <Button
        isLoading={loading}
        onClick={() => formSubmit()}
        fontSize={'md'}
        _hover={{}}
        color="white"
        fontWeight={'700'}
        mt={'5 !important'}
        size={'lg'}
        bg="#e50914"
      >
        Sign In
</Button>
```

Comment: `if (payload.email && payload.password) {` (you should also use state values for the input content, not get it from the DOM with refs)

Comment: It works!! Can you please explain to me what's the reason behind it

Comment: Your condition doesn't check both fields, one of them being non-empty is enough. But you need a logical AND here, i.e. `&&` so it only dispatches if *both* field values are non-empty.